# Search for pattern with alphanumeric and print the lines

Tags: awk

I have data in format

```
A  ((!(A1+A2)))
B  (A1A2)
C  (A1+A2)
D  (!(A1+A2)B1)
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  (!(!A1!A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1!A2)B1)
```

I want output as

```
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  (!(!A1!A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1!A2)B1)
```

I want to get that line which has `!` only with alphanumeric.

I used

```
awk -F' ' '$2 ~ /\!/' file
```

And this also

```
awk '$2'~/^[(!)_[:alnum:]]+[(!)+_[:alnum:]]+$/' file
```

But this is listing all the lines which has `!` along with `!` in alphanumeric also.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to get that line which has `!` only with alphanumeric:

You can just use this regex for matching `!` followed by an alphanumeric character:

```sh
/![[:alnum:]]/
```

awk command:

```sh
awk '$2 ~ /![[:alnum:]]/' file

E  (!A1+!A2)
F  (!(!A1!A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1!A2)B1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ grep '![[:alpha:]]' file
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  (!(!A1!A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1!A2)B1)

$ awk '/![[:alpha:]]/' file
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  (!(!A1!A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1!A2)B1)

$ sed -n '/![[:alpha:]]/p' file
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  (!(!A1!A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1!A2)B1)
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to more clearly state your requirements and provide sample input/output that that doesn't work for.

Answer (score 2):

I guess *I want to get that line which has `!` only with alphanumeric* means: not `!(`

```
$ awk '/![^(]/' file
```

Output:

```
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  (!(!A1!A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1!A2)B1)
```

If your real data is not so tight, you may want to throw in some space checking, for example: `/! *[^(]/`

Answer (score 2):

Also with `awk`:

```
awk '/![[:alpha:]]+/' file         
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  (!(!A1!A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1!A2)B1)
```

Or

```
awk '/![[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]/' file
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  (!(!A1!A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1!A2)B1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can require a starting (leading) word boundary (`\<`) after `!`:

```sh
awk '$2 ~ /!\</' file
```

Note that whitespace is the default field separator pattern, you do not need `-F' '`.

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/kcpmHu):

```sh
s='A  ((!(A1+A2)))
B  (A1A2)
C  (A1+A2)
D  (!(A1+A2)B1)
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  (!(!A1!A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1!A2)B1)'
awk '$2 ~ /!\</' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  (!(!A1!A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1!A2)B1)
```